# Location indicators in page headings: Which one is the most preferable?

Tags: navigation

In order to show the user they're on the right page after they clicked, there are several ways to treat this goal:

1. Text Headline over the Content, saying the same as the link they clicked before. E.g.: "Hot offers"
2. A teaser graphic with a photo and a text element, saying the same as the link they clicked before
3. If it is a distribution page showing other subpages, the heading shows a teaser featuring the most important of the subpages, e.g: "100+ Hot offers in section X"

I think about the [Cores&Paths](http://experienceblogger.com/post/676476635/wireframing-101-cores-paths)-approach, which encourages me to feature the core content. When I think about the user, he might as well be happy to have his click decision repeated.

Any ideas regarding this?

Answer (score 1):

The most overwhelmingly common pattern is the first. Look at the 'tags', 'users' and 'badges' tabs on this very site. For that reason alone, I'd suggest your users most expect the link name to match the page title.

Perhaps I've misunderstood the question, but if I clicked a link named 'Hot Offers', and saw solution #3 ("9001 hot offers in this section!"), I'd be confused. Is this actually the hot offers section, or just another section that happens to contain (some or all?) hot offers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Regarding the Num+"hot offers"-Problem:
I thought about a solution like this to give the User some more information about the Site content and to reduce the amount of information.
Just to clarify: The banner/teaser would show not only the page name, but would also preselect a topic and feature it.

Comment: Hmm. Saying '9001 hot offers' rather than 'Hot offers / 9001 offers in this section' IS quite space efficient, isn't it? I'd still say the issue I raise above would outweigh that advantage, though.